# How to Rename Image File on Upload Using this Script

Tags: php, image, upload

Please could someone show me where i need to change the code so that the image uploaded is renamed to "freddy" for e.g.

But still carries the correct existing extension i.e jpg, png, gif.

Thanks In Advance

```
<?php
// define a constant for the maximum upload size
 define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 1024 * 50);

if (array_key_exists('upload', $_POST)) {
// define constant for upload folder
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/home/richard/public_html/testing/editable-images/');
// replace any spaces in original filename with underscores


$file = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES['image']['name']);
// create an array of permitted MIME types
$permitted = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg',
'image/png');

// upload if file is OK
if (in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], $permitted)
  && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0 
  && $_FILES['image']['size'] <= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
switch($_FILES['image']['error']) {
  case 0:
    // check if a file of the same name has been uploaded
 // Uncomment to stop overwritten files >>>>      if (!file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $file))        {
      // move the file to the upload folder and rename it
      $success =
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR .
 $file);
// Uncomment to stop overwritten files  >>>>    } else {
//  Uncomment to stop overwritten files  >>>>       $result = 'A file of the same name             already exists.';
  // Uncomment to stop overwritten files  >>>>>      }
    if ($success) {
      $result = "$file uploaded successfully.";
    } else {
      $result = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
    }
    break;
  case 3:
  case 6:
  case 7:
  case 8:
    $result = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
    break;
  case 4:
    $result = "You didn't select a file to be uploaded.";
   }
  } else {
  $result = "$file is either too big or not an image.";
  }
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// get file extension
$ext = end(explode($_FILES['image']['name']));

// name your file and preserve file extension
$file = "freddy.".$ext;

// create an array of permitted MIME types
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Check description of method move_uploaded_file [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Hi, Peter, Your code has helped me, but the extension is not showing, the file is being uploaded like freddy. without any extension. 

Any ideas why that might be?

Thankyou

Comment: @Lucy change `list($ext)` to `$ext`